# Can I fetch a HTML input box from another domain to my domain without using iframes..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I've been trying to import an input box to my web page from another domain to my local domain using `.load` method. I even used `ajax` but all I get is an error in console saying ... **no access-control-allow-origin**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are being stopped by the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). This requires that all requests made client side must be within the current domain. Any requests to external domains will be blocked by the browser.

To retrieve content from another site you would either need to use an iframe, or make the external request on the server-side and then make the local AJAX request to that.

Comment: Yeah! that's right, but, I cannot make changes or add anything to the other domain. And can you please demonstrate with a code?? And I cannot use an iframe... :(

Comment: `<iframe src="http://otherdomain.com/path.html"></iframe>`. The server side solution is much too broad for this question. I would suggest having a google.